# Change C# language version to 7.2 in vs-code on Linux

Tags: visual-studio-code, c#-7.2

I read that `.NET Core 2.0` SDK support `C# 7.2` by default but the features of `C# 7.1` and `7.2` are disabled and we have to enable them.
I install both SDK and C# extension for vs-code, but when I compile my code I got this error:

> Program.cs(118,2): error CS1513: } expected [/home/smn/Desktop/myTest.csproj]
>
> The build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.

I also add these line to my `.csproj` file:

> `<PropertyGroup">
>       <LangVersion>7.2</LangVersion>
>       </PropertyGroup>`

try this too:

```
`<PropertyGroup">
<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>`
```

and also try this too:

```
`<PropertyGroup 
Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup 
Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>`
```

What should I do?!

Comment: That error looks like a syntax error not a direct sdk issue.

Comment: @ErnieDingo I build and run it successfully on C# 7.0.

Comment: That is indeed a strange bug. Could you post the line of code.  Maybe the lines preceding as well

Comment: Can you add `#error version` to your code and inspect the resulting diagnostic? This will confirm what compiler version is used and what language version it received.

Answer (score 16):

If you have not been able to solve this yet, you should try to remove the erroneous quote (") in the PropertyGroup tag, which appears in all the examples you gave.

```
<PropertyGroup">
```

This works for me:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>7.2</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: I was able to solve this problem by simply adding the `LangVersion` element to my csproj file with an acceptable version, in my case 7.1 or higher.